# Automatic Code completion in Eclipse 8.4?

Tags: c++, eclipse, autocomplete, code-completion, eclipse-luna

I recently installed Eclipse Luna(for win7) for developing C++ programs. The problem is the code completion only shows suggestions when I press Ctrl + Space button. I searched on the internet, but the only solution I was able to find is for old Eclipse(Java) version 3.4 or something. In that you have some text feilds in which you can enter the characters for auto-completion. But in 8.4 there are no such text-fields. Do they have a plugin for this? Please Help me

Answer (score 0):

Yes they've changed the behavior a bit. The auto completion list pops up at entering `.`, `->` or `::`, and as you mentioned with `CTRL + Space`

If the list popped up, press `TAB` once to get inside the popup selection list, and go up down with the arrow keys. Press enter to select one.

If the entered symbol is specified enough, to select a proposal, hitting `Space` after the dialog popped up, will autocomplete though.

Comment: No, I didn't asked that I know how to use auto-completion. Read the question carefully. I wanted to know that how can I make auto completion, popup suggestions automatically without the need of pressing Ctrl + Space everytime.I know it pops up at entering `.` `->` etc. But I want it for all my code. For example, when I want to use system() function, I will just have to type something like syst etc. then it will automatically popup suggestions for me to choose. Is that possible ?

Comment: @EdwardMckinzie _'Is that possible ?'_ I'm afraid no :-/ ... IIRC (a few hours ago), it behaved as I have described it.

Comment: Damn, I think I have to look for another IDE now. :'(

Comment: @EdwardMckinzie I actually can't really see what's your problem with the use of `CTRL Space`?

Comment: Pressing Ctrl+Space every time to get suggestions (specially when one is learning a new library or something) will slow down the speed(very much). Imo its a very unfriendly feature. So, making it automatic will help A lot and speedup the process.

Comment: @EdwardMckinzie Depends a bit, on how that library is structured regarding namespaces or unique prefixes for classes and functions, and what you actually have included and set as the defaults IMHO. After using it a few weeks now, I'm pretty comfortable with the behavior as is.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: you said that after pressing ctrl+space you have to press tab to get into the suggestion list. this is driven me crazy! you can use your arrow keys as normal, with the difference that only tab shows the dotted selection box... IMHO this is not a feature, its a bug... any suggestions?

Comment: @lifeOfPI You may try to report it as bug on Eclipse's site.